# Writing multiline text in pdf page

Tags: pdf

I want to write a multiline text, I've tried this:

```
6 0 obj
<</Length 59>>
stream
BT /F1 24 Tf 100 520 Td (This is test\n This is test)Tj ET
endstream
endobj
```

But I am not getting a new line. Is there a simple way to achieve that or I must create another stream with position of the next line?

This is the full code:

```
%PDF-1.5
1 0 obj <</Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj <</Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R] /Count 1>>
endobj
3 0 obj<</Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources 4 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 500 700] /Contents 6 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj<</Font <</F1 5 0 R>>>>
endobj
5 0 obj<</Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Helvetica>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Length 75>>
stream
BT 
/F1 24 Tf
100 520 Td
(This is test) Tj
T*
(This is test) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f
0000000009 00000 n
0000000059 00000 n
0000000116 00000 n
0000000219 00000 n
0000000259 00000 n
0000000328 00000 n
trailer <</Size 7/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
454
%%EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to do something like this:

```
BT 
/F1 24 Tf
30 TL
100 520 Td
(This is test) Tj
T*
(This is test) Tj
ET
```

or the shorter form:

```
BT 
/F1 24 Tf
30 TL
100 520 Td
(This is test) Tj
(This is test) '
ET
```

You might want to read up on section 9.4.3 *Text-Showing Operators* in the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

**P.S.:** Added text leading TL operators.

Comment: It still doesn't print the second line, I added full code to the post.

Comment: I forgot, you need to set the text leading when using T* or '... I'll edit the answer.

Comment: very good, without the TL second line just overwritten the previous line?